# Attempting to find the 5 largest values per month using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am attempting to show the top three values of `nc_type` for each month. I tried using `n_largest` but that doesn't do it by date.

Original Data:

```
     area                                     nc_type    occurred_date  
0     Filling                                 x          12/23/2015 0:00   
1     Filling                                 f          12/22/2015 0:00   
2     Filling                                 s          9/11/2015 0:00   
3     Filling                                 f          2/17/2016 0:00   
4     Filling                                 s          5/3/2016 0:00   
5     Filling                                 g          8/29/2016 0:00   
6     Filling                                 f          9/9/2016 0:00   
7     Filling                                 a          6/1/2016 0:00
```

Transformed with:

```
df.groupby([df.occurred_date.dt.month, "nc_type"])["rand"].count()
```

Transformed Data:

```
occurred_date  nc_type                                   
1              x                            3
               y                            4
               z                           13
               w                           24
               f                           34
                                           ..
12             d                           18
               g                           10
               w                           44
               a                           27
               g                           42
```

Comment: `df.groupby('occurred_date').nlargest(5)`?

Comment: Also, what is the last column's name? Or are the first two columns a multiindex?

Comment: The original dataset had many records with an `occurred_date` and `nc_type` associated and I used groupby to get to my current dataframe

Comment: We are being forced to make assumptions on what your data's structure is like. Would be nice if you could confirm with one of our answers. Thanks.

Comment: Added information about my original data

Comment: See scenario 1 of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Scenario 1**
*MultiIndex series*

```
occurred_date  nc_type
1.0            x           3
               y           4
               z          13
               w          24
               f          34
12.0           d          18
               g          10
               w          44
               a          27
               g          42
Name: test, dtype: int64
```

Call `sort_values` + `groupby` + `head`:

```
df.sort_values(ascending=False).groupby(level=0).head(2)

occurred_date  nc_type
12.0           w          44
               g          42
1.0            f          34
               w          24
Name: test, dtype: int64
```

Change `head(2)` to `head(5)` for your situation.

Or, expanding upon my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46880050/attempting-to-find-the-5-largest-values-per-month-using-groupby?noredirect=1#comment80707299_46880050) with `nlargest`, you could do:

```
df.groupby(level=0).nlargest(2).reset_index(level=0, drop=1)

occurred_date  nc_type
1.0            f          34
               w          24
12.0           w          44
               g          42
Name: test, dtype: int64
```

---

**Scenario 2**
*3-col dataframe*

```
   occurred_date nc_type  value
0            1.0       x      3
1            1.0       y      4
2            1.0       z     13
3            1.0       w     24
4            1.0       f     34
5           12.0       d     18
6           12.0       g     10
7           12.0       w     44
8           12.0       a     27
9           12.0       g     42
```

You can use `sort_values` + `groupby` + `head`:

```
df.sort_values(['occurred_date', 'value'], 
        ascending=[True, False]).groupby('occurred_date').head(2)

   occurred_date nc_type  value
4            1.0       f     34
3            1.0       w     24
7           12.0       w     44
9           12.0       g     42
```

Change `head(2)` to `head(5)` for your scenario.

---

**Scenario 3**
*MultiIndex Dataframe*

```
                       test
occurred_date nc_type      
1.0           x           3
              y           4
              z          13
              w          24
              f          34
12.0          d          18
              g          10
              w          44
              a          27
              g          42
```

Or, with `nlargest`.

```
df.groupby(level=0).test.nlargest(2)\
              .reset_index(level=0, drop=1)

occurred_date  nc_type
1.0            f          34
               w          24
12.0           w          44
               g          42
Name: test, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd include `group_keys=False`

```
df.groupby('occurred_date', group_keys=False).nlargest(3)

occurred_date  nc_type
1.0            f          34
               w          24
               z          13
12.0           w          44
               g          42
               a          27
Name: value, dtype: int64
```